# How to install fonts from the LaTeX font catalogue?

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex, fontspec

How can I install both fonts in the page http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamondx/ to work together?  My attempt so far was installing both as OpenType system fonts and using XeLaTeX with no success.  I'm currently using TeXworks and MikTeX on Windows 7.

Comment: the Type 1 version should be already installed. So you can use it in the same way as shown on that web page

Comment: Thanks Herbert and Kurt.  Does this Type 1 include the math supports?  Because as of right now all math characters are displayed regularly in Roman font.

Comment: And currently I'm getting LaTeX Error: File `garamondx.sty' not found, and Package mathdesign Warning: No font specified on input line 183.

Comment: Open the MiKTeX Package Manager and either install both `garamondx` and `mathdesign` or you see there, that they are already installed,  but because of the error message it is clear, that at least `garamondx` is not (properly) installed.

Answer (score 4):

The `garamondx` package and the URW GaramondNo8 fonts are not included in either TeX Live or MiKTeX because of their restrictive licences. The easiest way to install them is through the `getnonfreefonts` script—see the instructions at

http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

Michael

Comment: Michael, that’s not fully true: `garamondx` can in MiKTeX be installed with the package manager, I’ve done that – it is not part of the basic installer (but this could change in future releases). MiKTeX is not that restrictive like TeX Live (and `getnonfreefonts` is only for TeX Live). BTW thank you for your font providings!