# How to Install Garamondx font properly? Don't know how to create bitmap font for zgmr8r

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

I try to install the LaTeX package [`garamondx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/garamondx) and compile the doc which comes with the package. For this, I downloaded `garamondx.tds.zip` from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/fonts, extracted the archive to `$HOME/texmf` and run `texhash`. `updmap` doesn't work for my local user, because

```
Directory "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap" isn't writable
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I try to run the provided minimal example, I get the return error code 70:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 zgmr8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for zgmr8r.
mktexpk: perhaps zgmr8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
)
!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

I'm using texlive2012.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you already have a working TeX Live environment installed (with one of the methods listed [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html)) you should install nonfree fonts (like garamondx) according to [this](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) guide.

In short, first you download the [script](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts) and execute it (needs root privileges) with `texlua install-getnonfreefonts`. You'll see something like this

```
Detected System: x86_64-linux
Detected Installation: /usr/local/texlive/2012
mkdir /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/scripts/getnonfreefonts ...          [done]
Installing texmf/scripts/getnonfreefonts/getnonfreefonts.pl ...          [done]
Installing texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.1 ...                      [done]
Installing texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts-sys.1 ...                  [done]
Installing texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...               [done]
Installing texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts-sys.man1.pdf ...           [done]
md5sum: cf8aeec0477a28c0c32ba1166f8bd8f3 getnonfreefonts.pl ...            [ok]
md5sum: f850d910dd96ee27cecdb3772047d247 getnonfreefonts.1 ...             [ok]
md5sum: fb2b0f7699db8e627d4e26b730e94928 getnonfreefonts-sys.1 ...         [ok]
md5sum: 415b51f7c80a4abe8d0a667a04c9d525 getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...      [ok]
Fixing File Permissions ...                                              [done]
Creating symlinks in 'bin/x86_64-linux' ...                              [done]
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

Then run `getnonfreefonts -l` for a list of available fonts:

```
arial-urw      Arial (URW)                                  [not installed]
classico       Classico (URW)                               [not installed]
dayroman       DayRoman (Apostrophiclabs)                   [not installed]
eurofont       Euro symbols (Adobe)                         [not installed]
garamond       GaramondNo8 (URW)                            [not installed]
garamondx      GaramondNo8 Expert (Michael Sharpe)          [not installed]
lettergothic   LetterGothic (URW)                           [not installed]
luximono       LuxiMono (Bigelow & Holmes)                  [not installed]
vntex-nonfree  VnTeX nonfree (Han The Thanh)                [not installed]
webomints      Webomints (Galapagos Design Group)           [not installed]
```

and finally `getnonfreefonts garamondx` (`getnonfreefonts -a` to install all nonfree fonts). 
[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. The updmap-sys call failed, but after a manual texhash and updmap-sys everything seems to work. Now I try to find out how this font can be activated temporarily (probably using `\fontfamily`).

Comment: if map files cannot be updated when you have root privileges you may have something weird going on in your TeXLive installation, probably related to previous manual intervertions into the texmf-tree.

Comment: Probably. I think I got everything working. `\fontfamily{zgmx}` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @dcmst Does this install method only work in TexLive and not MiKTeX?

Comment: @Andy AFAIK only works for TeX Live, for MikTeX you should be able to install the garamondx font via the package manager (but I don't use MikTeX, so I'm not sure) see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/how-to-install-fonts-from-the-latex-font-catalogue for more info.

Comment: @dcsmt: though I just installed TexLive 2013 from scratch on my Ubuntu 12-04 machine, and got positive seeming responses from `sudo texhash` and `sudo updmap-sys`, I get

    (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./foo.aux)
    (/home/michaeln/texmf/tex/latex/uop/ot1uop.fd) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo.aux)
    kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 uopr8r
    mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for uopr8r.
    ...

Comment: @MichaelNorrish I think you should open a new question, maybe linking this one and stating that the proposed solution didn't work out for you. Worst case scenario, it will turn out to be a duplicate.

Comment: The `getnonfreefonts` script needs to be run as normal user again, as it will only install the fonts locally.

Answer (score 2):

For windows users you may follow the following steps (assuming textlive already installed):

1. run using command prompt :
   `curl --remote-name https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts`
   2.then `texlua install-getnonfreefonts --sys`
2. check installed fonts `getnonfreefonts --sys -l`
3. install all fonts `getnonfreefonts --sys -a` you may add name after -a but I have not test it to install specific font.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by running the `getnonfreefonts.pl` script installed by [`install-getnonfreefonts`](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts) with the options `--sys --refreshmap --all`.  This correctly updated the font maps.