# Why does scshape and bfseries in urw-garamond lead to slanted letters?

Tags: fonts, bold, small-caps, mathdesign, slanted

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
    {\bfseries \scshape Hello World!}

    {\bfseries Hello World!}

    {\scshape Hello World!}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

What's going on? Bold and caps both work, and even the combination "works", but "too well", it additionally slants the letters. How do I "unslant" it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font description file for URW-Garamond provided by `mathdesign` is wrong; here's a fixed version, where the erroneous lines have been commented out (for reference):

```
%Filename: t1mdugm.fd
%Created by: tex makevp
%Created using fontinst v1.933

%THIS FILE SHOULD BE PUT IN A TEX INPUTS DIRECTORY

\ProvidesFile{t1mdugm.fd}
   [2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/mdugm.]

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{mdugm}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{m}{it}{
   <-> mdugmri8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{m}{fic}{
   <-> mdugmrifc8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{m}{n}{
   <-> mdugmr8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{m}{fsc}{
   <-> mdugmrfc8t
%   <-> mdugmrofc8t%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< WRONG!
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{m}{sl}{
   <-> mdugmro8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{mb}{sl}{
   <-> mdugmmo8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{mb}{fsc}{
%   <-> mdugmmofc8t%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< WRONG!
   <-> mdugmmfc8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{mb}{n}{
   <-> mdugmm8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{mb}{it}{
   <-> mdugmmi8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{mb}{fic}{
   <-> mdugmmifc8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * mdugm/mb/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * mdugm/bx/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{bx}{fsc}{<->ssub * mdugm/mb/fsc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{b}{fsc}{<->ssub * mdugm/bx/fsc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdugm/mb/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{b}{n}{<->ssub * mdugm/bx/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * mdugm/mb/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{b}{it}{<->ssub * mdugm/bx/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{bx}{fic}{<->ssub * mdugm/mb/fic}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mdugm}{b}{fic}{<->ssub * mdugm/bx/fic}{}

\endinput
```

If I make a copy of the file in the working directory and fix the erroneous lines, the output is as expected:

[image]

Comment: I should add that I didn't do further testing. Maybe other fixes are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to also load `garamondx`, which will give you true small caps in all 4 weights/shapes (and old-style numbers + superior figures + all f-ligatures):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}

    {\bfseries \scshape Hello World!}

    {\bfseries \scshape\itshape Hello World!}

    {\bfseries Hello World!}

    {\scshape Hello World!}

    {\scshape\itshape Hello World!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Load _both_ packages? (And your MWE doesn't quite match the picture.)

Comment: Unrelatedly, I have troubles installing `garamondx` manually. `File 'garamondx.sty' not found.` After I installed it in the obscure way the package readme told me.

Comment: Absolutely. It's in the documentation of garamondx. It seems you have to load it *after* `mathdesign`. The code is corrected (a problem with my clipboard manager…)

Comment: Why don't you install it with your package manager?

Comment: I didn't know I can. I followed http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110057/how-to-install-garamondx-font-properly-dont-know-how-to-create-bitmap-font-for, but the error is still the same. Maybe it's Gentoo-specific?

Comment: Ah. I ran the script as root, which turns out to be the wrong thing to do. Now I have other errors. (But that's a separate question.)

Comment: Your distribution is TeX Live, on a Linux system?

Comment: The package is not included in TeX Live.

Comment: @cfr: I know, that's why I asked the question. But there exists a `garamondx.tds.zip` file, which should make it easy to install.

Comment: `getnonfreefonts-sys` is the best way to install it.

Comment: Probably. I don't know the details, as I am under MiKTeX.