# `New TX Math` Package not compatible with `underbrace`

Tags: incompatibility, newtxmath, underbrace, garamondx

I am trying to use an `underbrace` option with `Garamond Expert with NewTX Math` and for some reason the pdf is not generated for the following code as there seem to be some compatibility issues even though no errors are shown.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}


\begin{document}

\[
    S_{classical}[q] = \int\displaylimits_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} ds\ 
    \underbrace{\left( \frac{m}{3} \frac{t}{2}  \right)  }
\]

\end{document}
```

On the other hand if I remove the `\frac{t}{2}` or `\frac{m}{3}` then the code compiles. Basically, if I use multiple terms inside the `\left(` and `\right)` environment then the pdf is not generated even though the code compiles with no errors or warnings.

Another point to note is that if I remove the line `\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}` then everything works fine but the font I want to use is not the same.

Please suggest me what to do. I have looked at the [documentation](http://mirror.iopb.res.in/tex-archive/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf) for the `NewTX Math` package but couldn't find anything.

Edit 1 :

It seems that it is absolutely not possible to use `\left[` and `\right]` with the `NewTX Math` package anywhere in the document.

Also, I can't use `\underbrace{\left( \frac{m}{3} hi \right)}` if the `\left(` and `\right)` are inside `\underbrace` but if they are outside then it is fine.

Edit 2 :

It seems that wherever the pdf is not generated there is a file named `missfont.log` which is generated with the following entry `mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 txex-bar`. So I ran `apt-file search txex-bar` which told me to expect this file with two extensions : `tfm` and `pfb`, then I ran a `kpsewhich` on both and sure enough both are present whereas `myfilename.log` shows that `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file txex-bar): Font txex-bar at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Edit 3 :

Forcing `latexmk` to compile results in the following :

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 txex-bar
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for txex-bar.
mktexpk: perhaps txex-bar is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file txex-bar): Font txex-bar at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Failure to make 'a.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, in force_mode: so I tried finishing targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 256
```

Comment: What TeX Distribution are you using? Is it up to date? I have not problem typesetting your sample with a fully up to date TeX Live 2020.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I am using `texlive` but I have also tried `texmaker` and `latexilla`. Sorry, TeXLive is 2015/Debian.

Comment: If you can use luatex or xetex, you could load `unicode-math` instead and `\setmathfont{Garamond Math}`. Using the modern tools cuts a lot of Gordian knots.

Comment: @Davislor I just tried that and it says that the font is not found!

Comment: It should be in the latest distribution, or [the package is on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/garamond-math?lang=en).

Comment: @Davislor I updated my distribution but it only goes upto 2015 version. I have trouble with the package installation from CTAN and actually would rather use `pdflatex` with the above method if someone can help me make it work.

Comment: Is it related to [this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110057/how-to-install-garamondx-font-properly-dont-know-how-to-create-bitmap-font-for)

Comment: @Davislor I used that script initially but it wasn't working. So, I installed `texlive-fonts-extra` which enabled me to use `Garamond` but then the `underbrace` comannd ran into issues.

Answer (score 3):

On my TeX Live 2020 system, I was able to compile your MWE by installing [the getnonfreefonts script](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts) and running the `getnonfreefonts.pl` script it installed with `--sys --refreshmap --all`.  This correctly installed the map files for the Type 1 version of GaramondX.

If you can use luatex or xetex, I would recommend `unicode-math` with the Garamond Math font instead.

Here was the output from a very slightly-modified version (I changed the word in the subscript to the operator font.)

[image: GaramondX/newtx sample]

Comment: It compiles without errors but there is no pdf generated. Can you post a screenshot of your pdf? Can you try this as well : `\frac{mesopotamia}{3}` instead of `frac{m}{3}`. I now suspect the problem has to do with the length of the underbrace. If it is working for you then I will remove my TeXLive 2015 and do an install for TexLive 2020. I have used the script and it does not make things work for me. Also, as I have clearly demonstrated in the question : the problem is **NOT** with Garamond font but with the `NewTX Math` package.

Comment: @Nitin Added image.

Comment: Lastly, Can you try this as well : `\frac{mesopotamia}{3}` instead of `frac{m}{3}`. If this works then I have no option but to remove current distribution and do a fresh install of latest one.

Comment: @Nitin Works just fine. You might consider `\mathrm{mesopotamia}` or `\operatorname{mesopotamia}`, BTW.

Comment: Then I guess there is no choice but to remove this distribution and get the latest one. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Nitin It is always best to use the updated set....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Agreed. There’s no reason to feel reticent about upgrading. The maintainers never knowingly break old documents. (Or TeX/LaTeX would be a lot less complicated today.)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work and in case anyone stumbles upon the exact same problem I am providing some information here.

The problem is actually with the the `TeXLive 2015` distribution where the `NewTX Math` has a few problems with execution. If one upgrades to `TeXLive 2020` things work out.