# Bold garamondx font looks like computer modern in math mode

Tags: math-mode, bold, computer-modern, garamondx

I'm using the garamond font from the **garamondx** package.
Using the following commands

```
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
```

effectively changes the text font but I realized that the bold font in math mode was not garamond anymore. It looks to me like the default Computer Modern Roman font (image attached). Is this normal ? Is the **garamondx** package not supporting bold font in math mode ?

[image]

Here's the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    r \, \bm{r}   \\
    h \, \bm{h}   \\
    v \, \bm{v}   \\
    a \, \bm{a}   \\
    b \, \bm{b}   \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Have you installed the font of garamondx? http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/garamondx.tds.zip

Comment: Yes, I installed the font following this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110057/how-to-install-garamondx-font-properly-dont-know-how-to-create-bitmap-font-for

The package does work when I type regular text or equations without bold characters. Does it have the same behavior for you?

Comment: I have not the font installed. :-(

Answer (score 10):

I found the problem ! All you had to do was load the package **garamondx** before loading the **bm** package. This example works for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    r \, \bm{r}   \\
    h \, \bm{h}   \\
    v \, \bm{v}   \\
    a \, \bm{a}   \\
    b \, \bm{b}   \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```