# Trying to install garamondx on MikTeX with getnonfreefonts results in error

Tags: miktex, garamondx

As [also mentioned elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350790/30481), the `garamondx` has been marked as obsolete in one of the last MikTeX updates.

As suggested in various questions ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110062/30481), or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88119/30481)) and also on the [garamondx README](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/fonts/garamondx/README), I tried to get back `garamondx` using the `getnonfreefonts` script, following the instructions found [here](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/).

However, when running `texlua.exe ./install-getnonfreefonts` the script fails with the error (I'm using Windows 10):

```
./install-getnonfreefonts:890: attempt to concatenate global 'texdir' (a nil value)
```

The lines in the script around L890 are

```
kpse.set_program_name('texlua')
texdir=kpse.var_value('SELFAUTOPARENT')
bindir=kpse.var_value('SELFAUTODIR')
exedir=kpse.var_value('SELFAUTOLOC')
texmflocal=kpse.var_value('TEXMFLOCAL')

if isdir(texdir .. '/texmf') then
  texmf_dir='/texmf'
else
  texmf_dir='/texmf-dist'
end
```

with L890 being the line starting with `if isdir(...)`.

However, I don't know enough about lua to be able to diagnose what is causing this problem.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Does it even support `miktex`? Only `texlive` is mentioned on its website.

Comment: @daleif I actually just assumed it did for some reason, but now that you say it you're probably right, MikTex is not mentioned anywhere on the page. I guess I'll have to use one of the other methods listed on the garamondx README page for MikTeX then (which fail to work for other reasons, but that is a different story). Thanks anyway

Comment: at the end I solved the problem as explained in [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371058/30481)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP solved the problem by himself.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik fair (though I don't see the close button on my own post?)

Comment: @glS There is a minimum reputation to see and to cast close/repoen votes. Can you see the button now? ;)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik ah, I didn't remember about that rep threshold. I see it now, thanks! (though I thought that vtc your own question automatically closed it! it must be only above another rep threshold)

Comment: oh, I see its because it wasn't flagged as duplicate but as OT. I would have thought duplicate to be a better fit but no big deal