# Installing garamondx on MiKTeX following README page gives error on `initexmf.exe --edit-config-file updmap`

Tags: miktex, garamondx

I've been trying to install `garamondx` on MiKTeX (on a Windows 10 machine) after it was marked as obsolete and removed in a recent MiKTeX update.

Following the instructions on the [garamondx README page](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/fonts/garamondx/README), I downloaded `garamondx.tds` from CTAN, unzipped it, and run the two following instructions (after cding into the unzipped folder):

```
initexmf --update-fndb
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
```

While the first one completes without warnings, the second one fails with the following message:

```
C:\Users\yourname\Downloads\garamondx.tds> initexmf.exe --edit-config-file updmap
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/yourname/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

The relevant lines on the mentioned `.log` file are

```
2017-05-22 11:19:33,907+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6234 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-05-22 11:19:33,940+0100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

2017-05-22 11:19:33,940+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="GitPad"
2017-05-22 11:19:33,940+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp
2017-05-22 11:19:33,940+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 68
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this even supposed to work on Windows?

---

Given that from the log it emerges that miktex is trying to use `GitPad`, I checked and realized (after suggestion in the comments) that the system variable `EDITOR` was set to `GitPad` for me (for reasons unknown to me).
Changing the value of this variable with `$env:EDITOR = Notepad` on powershell, I tried running the command again.
It still fails with the same error, but now the log registers an error at a different line:

```
2017-05-22 15:33:01,899+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6234 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-05-22 15:33:01,954+0100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 193.
2017-05-22 15:33:01,954+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="Notepad", commandLine="Notepad C:\Users\lk\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/config\updmap.cfg"
2017-05-22 15:33:01,954+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp
2017-05-22 15:33:01,954+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 270
```

What is the expected value of the `EDITOR` variable?

Comment: Why is miktex trying to use "GitPad" as editor? Did you change this somewhere? Or did you set an environment variable?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I definitely did not, I assume it was something internal to MiKTeX, but now I see it comes with git. Where does miktex take the program to use to open its files? Is it some internal variable?

Comment: It uses the value of the EDITOR environment variable or some default if it isn't set.  What do you get if you do `echo %EDITOR%`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it doesn't give anything because I think on windows 10 that is not the way you look at variables, but `$env:EDITOR` does give `GitPad`, and looking at the output of `env` confirms that this is the case. I have no idea where this setting came from. However, changing it to `Notepad` results in the same problem, only with the log now giving error at Line 270 instead of 68. What is the expected value of `EDITOR`?

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and `echo %EDITOR%` works fine for me (when I set the variable). Are you using a standard command line? By default (if EDITOR is not set) miktex uses notepad.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having found what the problem was and how to solve it, I figured it may be useful for someone else landing here due to a similar issue.

The reason of malfunction was indeed very simple: I was using a non-standard windows shell (powershell and the linux bash shell on windows). In there, the `EDITOR` system variable was set to `GitPad` (probably set by some git installation, I'm not sure), but even setting it back to a different value, like `Notepad`, using `$env:EDITOR = Notepad` didn't work and gave the error reported in the edit in the main question.

The solution was to simply switch back to using `cmd`. In there, the `EDITOR` variable was not set, and `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` opened a notepad window as expected, so that I could continue following the [instructions on the README page](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/fonts/garamondx/README).

To be fair though, those didn't really work, and `garamondx.sty` was still not found. Some more digging lend me [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88424/30481), where I learnt that I had to create a local `texmf` tree. I found the instructions to do this on [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/30481): I opened `MiKTeX Settings (Admin)`, there in the `Roots` tab I added the folder where I unzipped `garamondx.tds`, and then I clicked in the `General` tab `Refresh FNDB` and then `Update Formats`.

But this still wasn't enough! 
Files with `\usepackage{garamondx}` still didn't compile, and in the log file the following error (among others) was reported:

```
pdflatex.EXE (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 600 not found
```

Again, some more digging lend me to [this last post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55901/30481). It turns out I probably run `updmap` instead of `updmap-sys` somewhere along the road (quite possible given that I've been trying a lot of things to make this work), which you apparently [should absolutely avoid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255711/30481)!
Anyway, this resulted in 2 `pdftex.map` files on my computer, one in the TeX system and one in my personal tree.
I removed the one in my personal tree and finally I could compile files with `garamondx` again.

What a ride!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your instructions!
First, I used

`\usepackage{fontspec}`
`\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{EB Garamond}`

However, in *EB Garamond*, bold fonts were missing.
So, I decided to use `\usepackage{garamondx}` and ran through your installation instructions. Luckily, I did not have to do the second part about the `pdftex.map`.