# Garamond Italic font: First capital letter looks strange

Tags: fonts, fontspec, italic, italic-correction, garamond

I am using the *Garamond* font, included by the *fontspec* package:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond}
```

In my opinion, the first capital letter in italics looks strange.
It does not fit to the rest of the word.

Example 1:

[image: Letter V looking strange]

Example 2:

[image: Letter I looking strange]

I guess it's actually a characteristic of the font, not a problem of TeX.

Did anyone have the same problem? And how did you solve it?

Comment: Is it a necessity, that it is Garamond?

Comment: No, it could be a similar font.

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong with your font, but those italics look cursed. And I'm not just talking about the capitals either. For example, the *m* is noticeably more slanted than the *n* and the *r* and the *a*, the top of the *a* seems to fall just a little short of the [mean line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_line), and the kerning looks kind of wobbly too. All the letter shapes look good on their own, but it's like nobody's paid _any_ attention to how they fit together. (Actually, maybe that _is_ the case — maybe those italics are designed for use in math mode only?)

Comment: Related question on Graphic Design: [Why is Garamond italic all wonky?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/47050/19174)

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: Yes, that's true. I really wondered because *Garamond* actually is a standard font for typesetting books, but it looks so wobbly.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Thanks for the link!

Comment: @JavAlex Worth bearing in mind that 'Garamond' is really a general style (named after a person); the one here is the same as the Windows system Garamond font, and is pretty bad in the ways you've identified. There are other much better fonts in the family; it's just unfortunate that the most widely available instance is (a) bad (b) confusingly named the same as the whole style of typefaces.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### EB Garamond

I always like to support Open Source/Open License, so consider using OFL Licensed [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/).

[image: EB Garamond sample]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}

\noindent\textit{Variante 1a:}\\
Idealerweise sollte

\bigskip

\noindent wir im \textit{Il Cormorano}

\end{document}
```

It's also available as Type 1 on CTAN if you want to use pdflatex instead of xelatex. See [its listing in the LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ebgaramond/).

You can of course take out "Numbers=Lining" if you'd rather have oldstyle numerals.

Other free options include [Cormorant Garamond](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/cormorantgaramond/), [GaramondX](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamondexpertmathdesign/), [URW Garamond](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamond/) and [Garamond Libre](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamondlibre/).

### GaramondX

[image: GaramondX]

Comment: Installation instructions for *garamondx* on Windows with MikTex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371058/installing-garamondx-on-miktex-following-readme-page-gives-error-on-initexmf-ex

Comment: Of those, only Cormorant Garamond and EB Garamond seem to have the proper old style numerals.